# Retrieving Records from Multiple Tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How to select records from multiple table

Table "users":
user_id|username|email|login|password

Table "users_log"
log_id|user_id|status|timestamp|message

Table "users_balance"
balance_id|user_id|status|amount

Table "users_roles"
role_id|status|role_name

Table "users_role"
role_id|user_id

how to retrieving all records by user email and log status and user role

Output:
log-timestamp|user_id|Username|email|role_name|balance-amount|log-message

Comment: Please provide sample data, expected output and what have you attempted so far!

Comment: Hello,Welcome, you can use JOIN in MySQL. Please refer https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this I'm guessing.

```
SELECT 
 log.timestamp AS log_timestamp, 
 u.user_id, 
 u.username AS user_name, 
 u.email AS user_email,
 role.name AS role_name,
 bal.amount AS balance_amount,
 log.message AS log_message
FROM users AS u 
JOIN users_role AS ur ON ur.user_id = u.user_id
JOIN users_roles AS role ON role.role_id = ur.role_id
JOIN users_log AS log ON u.user_id = log.user_id
LEFT JOIN users_balance AS bal ON bal.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE u.email = @UserEmail
  AND role.role_name = @RoleName
  AND log.status = @LogStatus
```

And then set or replace the @UserEmail, @RoleName, @LogStatus variables by what you're looking for.

But depending on the data you might want to add a [GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) and an [aggregate function](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/aggregate-function.php) like MAX or SUM,  and perhaps extra criteria in the WHERE or [HAVING](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **JOIN** query to get data from multiple tables

Please try this,

```
SELECT usr.*,usrlg.*,usrbl.*,usrrl.*,usrrls.* FROM users AS usr JOIN users_log AS usrlg ON(usrlg.user_id=usr.user_id) JOIN users_balance AS usrbl ON (usrbl.user_id=usr.user_id)
JOIN users_role AS usrrl ON(usrrl.user_id=usr.user_id) JOIN users_roles AS usrrls ON(usrrls.role_id=usrrl.role_id)
 WHERE usr.email='value' AND usrlg.status='value' AND usrrls.role_name='value'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through joins. Can refer below links.

https://www.guru99.com/joins.html

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm